# Running a project built in docker in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, docker

Sorry if I am being ignorant but I am quite confused on
How to run this project in `eclipse`:
https://github.com/ivanlomba/taboleiro

It was packed with `docker` and I have no experience with it whatsoever.
If anyone could help me out it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Eclipse user, but It's a Spring Boot application and uses Maven as build tool, so you can import the project (files inside code folder) as "Existing maven project". There are tons of tutorials about creating/importing a Spring Boot project with Eclipse and Maven if you have any doubts.

If you don't use Docker you will need to configure the mysql database manually. You can find the schema of the database inside resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

Docker part is only to deploy. Search for how to set up environment variables in your OS.

1. get Java 8 or newer, make sure the folder above bin of Java is defined as JAVA_HOME (like if your javac.exe path is "c:\program files\java\java8_121\bin\javac.exe" then JAVA_HOME="c:\program files\java\java8_121" without slash in the end
2. Download maven, unzip to a folder like c:\apps\maven then add the parent of the bin folder as MAVEN_HOME
   like  MAVEN_HOME=c:\apps\maven\maven_4_xyz
3. Change the PATH variable to be

PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

Now in termimal cd to the code folder of where you have cloned or unzipped https://github.com/ivanlomba/taboleiro/tree/master/code then give the commands

```
mvn install
mvn test
```

Now in IDE install maven plugin too if its not there, then can import as an existing maven project.

If your in linux change the paths to 
MAVEN_HOME=/path/maven_4_xyz
and
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$MVN_HOME/bin:$PATH

in ~/.profile or other place